# How to reference a non docker IP address inside a container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When using a `docker-compose` file, I can make reference to a container by it's name from within other containers.

```
version: '3'
network:
  mynet:
    external: false
services:
  database:
    image: mariadb
    network:
    - mynet
  application:
    build: .
    network:
    - mynet
```

The above means I can reference the database like so: `database:3306` from inside the `application` container.

Is there a way for me to add a non-docker ip address that can be referenced the same way? Say my `database` server is not managed by docker, but I want to reference it inside the `application` the same way?

`links` are deprecated I know, but I would like to be able to do something like:

services:
  application:
    build: .
    links:
    - "127.0.0.10:database"

Is something like this possible without `links`?

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this through environment variables that the application would be looking for. For example, the application code could use the environment variable called `DATABASE_URL` and then you just need to make sure it is set when the Docker image runs. Using your `docker-compose.yml` file above as a base, you can pass the database url like so:

```
version: '3'
network:
  mynet:
    external: false
services:
  database:
    image: mariadb
    network:
    - mynet
  application:
    build: .
    network:
    - mynet
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "mysql://username:password@my-database-url:3306"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wanting to avoid using ENV vars, and luckily found `extra_hosts` which does the job (I think, not tested it yet).

Comment: @designermonkey why are you avoiding envvars

Comment: It's a legacy app with already 100+ env vars (using .env files) I want to try another approach.

Comment: @designermonkey sometimes the best way is the simplest way. Plus since this is something that will, I assume, be changing between environments, an env var is the most straightforward approach.